# date in titlepage

Tags: titles, titling

So I want to create a titlepage for my document and I would like to print the last date of compilation on it but I can't seem to be able to. I've found people with similar problem but somehow haven't been able to make the solutions work for me.

here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{1cm}

    \Huge
    \textbf{Thesis Title}

    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \LARGE
    Thesis Subtitle

    \vspace{1.5cm}

    \textbf{Author Name}

    \vfill

    A thesis presented for the degree of\\
    Doctor of Philosophy

    \vspace{0.8cm}

    \Large
    Department Name\\
    University Name\\
    Country\\
    \date 

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

I have tried to use the titling package but it prints the date in english and I want it in french.

Comment: Use `\today`, not `\date`

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage[french]{babel}
...
\today % date in French
```

try that just before your begin document

Comment: Hi thanks, I actually already have babel in place but it doesn't seem to work with the titling package

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: sorry, tried to help :(